# How to Display Post Excerpts in Admin by Default?

Tags: wp-admin, excerpt

By default in the admin the Excerpt is hidden. See below.

[image: By default in the admin the Excerpt is hidden]

I would like to make it show up by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The names of unchecked boxes in `Screen Options` for `Edit Post` screen are stored in user's meta, per individual user, as an array. Insert the following code in your theme's `functions.php`:

```
function wpse_edit_post_show_excerpt( $user_login, $user ) {
    $unchecked = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'metaboxhidden_post', true );
    $key = array_search( 'postexcerpt', $unchecked );
    if ( FALSE !== $key ) {
        array_splice( $unchecked, $key, 1 );
        update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'metaboxhidden_post', $unchecked );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'wpse_edit_post_show_excerpt', 10, 2 );
```

This will update user's meta ( after successful login ) by removing `postexcerpt` name from the array of unchecked boxes names.

**Note**: to avoid losing your change, create a child theme and put the code into its `functions.php`.

Comment: Thank you, Frank! For reference, if anyone ever reads this down the road and wants to make sure this change is reflected immediately using this method I'd just change the SALTs in the wp-config.php to force everyone to login again and reflect these changes. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Sharing a slight modification of Franks' solution.  In my case, I don't want users to ever hide the excerpt so I've hooked the function to the `admin_init` instead of `wp_login`.

Frank's function executes when the user logs into the site which means that once the user is logged in they can hide it again. This solution will fire every time an admin page is loaded which wilmake it impossible for the user to hide the field.

```
function wpse_edit_post_show_excerpt() {
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  $unchecked = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'metaboxhidden_post', true );
  $key = array_search( 'postexcerpt', $unchecked );
  if ( FALSE !== $key ) {
    array_splice( $unchecked, $key, 1 );
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'metaboxhidden_post', $unchecked );
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_edit_post_show_excerpt', 10 );
```

Comment: The above one won't allow users to choose regardless. If they logout and login, then it will reset, not keeping their preferences. This answer makes more sense. I'd be interested to see if there's a way to hide the checkbox from the Screen Options. I might post a related question soon.

Comment: @StephenSabatini Add a link to the new question here once posted, if you you don't mind.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/282383

Comment: @StephenSabatini See response

Comment: Accepted your answer on the other post. For this question, for some reason it just started giving warnings and isn't working. Warning:  array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in /wp-content/themes/theme-name/functions.php on line 315.
Warning:  array_splice() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /wp-content/themes/theme-name/functions.php on line 317.

Comment: That means that `get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'metaboxhidden_post', true );` is returning `0` or `1` instead of an array.  Try this:  `$unchecked = ( is_array($unchecked = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'metaboxhidden_post', true ) ) ? $unchecked : array();
`

Comment: Seems to silence the error but still is not working.

Comment: That's the intent, we're casting the return of `metaboxhidden_post ` to an array if it's anything else.  Could you echo the `typeof` of the return... Curious if it's a boolean or something else.

Answer (score 2):

neither solution worked for me - but this "duct tape" css fix worked for me:

```
/* always show excerpt .. hide display options */
add_action('admin_head', 'myplugin_modify_admin_header');
function myplugin_modify_admin_header() {
  ?>
  <style type='text/css'> 
    #postexcerpt { display: block !important; } 
    label[for=postexcerpt-hide] { display: none !important; }
  </style>
  <?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While user meta stores unchecked meta boxes as an array, it does not store anything if the user has not modified the original defaults, returning a blank string instead. This results in errors on login if not accounted for, so I added an extra function & hook to cover all bases. I also wrapped the unchecked variable with a conditional to make sure it didn't error if nothing was returned. Thanks to [Role-Editor](https://www.role-editor.com/show-excerpt-field-in-post-editor/) for the additional function.

```
function wpse_edit_post_show_excerpt() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $unchecked = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'metaboxhidden_post', true );
    if(!empty($unchecked)){
        $key = array_search( 'postexcerpt', $unchecked );
        if ( FALSE !== $key ) {
            array_splice( $unchecked, $key, 1 );
            update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'metaboxhidden_post', $unchecked );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_edit_post_show_excerpt', 10 );

function show_excerpt_meta_box($hidden, $screen) {
    if ( 'post' == $screen->base ) {
        foreach($hidden as $key=>$value) {
            if ('postexcerpt' == $value) {
                unset($hidden[$key]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $hidden;
}
add_filter( 'default_hidden_meta_boxes', 'show_excerpt_meta_box', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Frank's solution; I discovered that new users do not have `metaboxhidden_post` defined yet, we need to define it in order to toggle on the excerpt field. I've specified a few fields to toggle off when we set it for the first time. Plus you'll notice a bit more validation here to prevent entries in our error_log.

```
function edit_post_show_excerpt( $user_login, $user ) { 
    /* if user can edit posts */
    $allowed_roles = array( 'editor', 'administrator', 'author' );
    if ( array_intersect( $allowed_roles, $user->roles ) ) {
        /* metaboxhidden_post contains list of fields that have been toggled off */
        $unchecked = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'metaboxhidden_post', true );

        if (is_array($unchecked)) {
            /* check metaboxhidden_post array for 'postexcerpt' key  */
            $key = array_search( 'postexcerpt', $unchecked );
            if ( FALSE !== $key ) {
                array_splice( $unchecked, $key, 1 );                
                update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'metaboxhidden_post', $unchecked );
            }
        } else{
            /* user does not yet have metabox preferences, so let's set them by default */
            $hide_fields =  array(              
                //'authordiv',
                //'categorydiv',
                //'commentstatusdiv',
                'formatdiv',
                //'postcustom',
                //'postexcerpt',
                //'postimagediv',
                'slugdiv',
                //'tagsdiv-post_tag',
                'trackbacksdiv',
            );
            update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'metaboxhidden_post', $hide_fields );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'edit_post_show_excerpt', 10, 2 );
```