# How to Remove Checkbox for Excerpt Under Screen Options

Tags: wp-admin, excerpt

In relation to [How to Display Post Excerpts in Admin by Default?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/275977), how would we go about removing the checkbox for Excerpt under screen options entirely for a complete solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with CSS.

```
.metabox-prefs label[for="postexcerpt-hide"] { 
    display: none; 
}
```

**In regard to adding the CSS to the admin section, you have two options:**

Option 1: Add the CSS to a stylesheet and enqueue it using the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook.

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style() {
  wp_register_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

Option 2: Add the CSS to a style tag using the `admin_head` hook.

```
function remove_post_excerpt_checkbox() {
  ?>
    <style>
      .metabox-prefs label[for="postexcerpt-hide"] { 
        display: none; 
      }
    </style>
  <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'remove_post_excerpt_checkbox' );
```